# Test network - subnet or VLAN?

Tags: vlan, subnet

We want to setup a small network on our corporate network which will emulate the setup that would be in place at our customers' sites.

We have a Windows 2016 server which we want to use as a DHCP server, but we obviously don't want it to affect the existing networks DHCP and Exchange servers.

For the main part, this network wants to be invisible to the rest of the network. However, the server will also be used as a build machine as well as a demo server, so we need to be able to access it from the corporate network.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way many companies do this safely is to install a firewall between the production and test networks. You can use the firewall to permit or deny traffic as needed, even down to individual hosts if that is required, allowing the production network access to the test network, while denying most access from the test network to the production network.

In other words, you could require any communications between the networks to be initiated from the production network. Simply setting up a test VLAN with its own subnet could endanger the production network if anything goes wrong on the test network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If we only needed communication with the server from the production network, would it be possible to have Nic1 set with a static ip, subnet and gateway of the production network. Then have nic2 with a static ip on a different subnet and have the server setup to serve dhcp requests on the other subnet. The more I think about it, the less I think we'd need communication between the two networks, just access to the server from both networks?

Comment: OK. It is up to you. We can't design your network, and primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic here. We can give you things like best practices and experiences.